# EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION on glDrawElements when using Windows

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, glfw

I'm using Java 8 and LWJGL to make a game engine with GLFW and OpenGL. I have a generic IndexedVAO class with all my VAO code in it to simplify things. Here are the relevant parts:

**Constructor**

```
    GL30.glBindVertexArray(vertexArrayObject);
    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferObject);
    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBufferObject);
    for(VertexAttribPointer prr : format.parts) {
        GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(prr.index);
        GL20.glVertexAttribPointer(prr.index, prr.size, prr.type,
            prr.normalized, prr.stride, prr.ptr);
    }
    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);
```

**Upload Function**

```
    data.flip();
    index.flip();
    this.numberOfIndicies = index.limit() / 2;
    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferObject);
    GL15.glBufferData(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, data, bufferUse);
    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBufferObject);
    GL15.glBufferData(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, index, bufferUse);
    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

**Draw Function**

```
    GL30.glBindVertexArray(vertexArrayObject);
    GL11.glDrawElements(this.drawmode, this.numberOfIndicies, GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0L);
    GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);
```

The code works fine on linux, but today I tried it on a windows machine and got an EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION jvm crash. When I checked the hs_err_pid#### file the JVM generates when it crashes I figured out the error was caused by a call to glDrawElements. It was the first glDrawElements call in the whole application, and commenting it out just moved the exception to the next one. I spent my whole afternoon moving code around and doing research and I got nowhere. It's not shader-related, glDrawArrays works in it's place, and considering it works fine on linux means it has nothing to do with any of the vertex generation code because it's all the same java code.

One major hardware difference between the two machines is that the windows machine has an older radeon graphics card and the linux machine has a recent geforce card in it, both have the latest drivers. I booted linux on the radeon machine to see if it was an inconsistency between vendors but when I finished waiting 30 minutes for java to install everything worked fine, which means this is OS specific. To verify I had my friend test it on his windows 10 machine and he also got the EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION.

**TL; DR: the above code works on linux but on windows it causes an EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION jvm crash**

Comment: Do you have a valid OpenGL context > 3.0 requested? @Spektre: Yeah, you can rant about windows and claim (wrong) things without proof, or you could try to help op.

Comment: @BDL If you look closer I tried to help ... the solution is to reinstall correct gfx driver. This is now a notorious "bug" of Win10 ... among others (what are they doing with drivers these days is hideous)

Comment: An ACCESS_VIOLATION in the draw function usually has one of two reasons 1) The draw function itself is not loaded and thus the program tries to execute a null function pointer, or 2) The draw function tries to access a buffer outside of it's size. Unfortunately, we don't see any of the values passed in the VAO setup nor do we see which data gets drawn.

Comment: @Spektre Yes both of the windows machines were using vendor specific drivers, not the windows update ones.

Comment: @BDL I am requesting an opengl 3.3 context in the glfw window hints and printing the opengl version says it's the 3.3 core profile on both machines

Comment: @LAX1DUDE Well than the only thing apart the other comments here that comes into my mind is that in the past I got a problem with older ATI/AMD cards and Windows. The only type usable for **VBO** `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER`  was 32bit `GLuint` any other type was unstable or crashing. Also AMD gfx drivers tend to be very sensitive to memory leaks so if any present in your app it might cause your problems too (even ones non related to graphics).

Comment: @Spektre So you're suggesting I should use integers instead of shorts in my element array buffer?

Comment: @LAX1DUDE its worth the try in the past when I dealt with this only the 32 bit unsigned ones worked as should (16 bits was crashing in driver all the time) but that was years ago so the things might changed ...

Comment: @Spektre I rewrote the index buffer code to use unsigned ints instead of unsigned shorts and it made no difference

Comment: @Spektre I just tested it on a windows machine with an nvidia graphics card, also running windows 7, and it was working there so it has to be some weird problem specific to windows with amd graphics

Comment: @LAX1DUDE Yep Windows AMD drivers are a bit picky. As I mentioned  check for memory leaks in your App (that is the most probable cause of problem) also they are sometimes picky in pixel formats (sometimes changing the bit widths help) recently (like 1-2 years) they can not handle rendering to texture with transparency (but that just do not render without any crash). But as I am not a Java coder it might be related to some JVM bug too (but that is improbable).

Comment: @LAX1DUDE I deal with this sorts of thing for last 10 years as I am Dev on Windows platform and using nVidia but target machines are usually with IntelHD or ATI/AMD Radeons  and you would not believe the kind of weird stuff they can throw at you (sometimes its even specific card related). And the things have tendency to be worse and worse in recent year or so not even fixed pipeline old style api is safe anymore (yes its depreceated for a while but the new stuff does not work reliably or at all in some cases so what else to use?)

Comment: While driver bugs cannot be ruled out (one crash in a related area on windows drivers which I experienced recently was that when one tried to do `glDrawElements` with byte offset which was not 4byte-aligned), I really think one should not jump to conclusions. You should still try to create a _minimal_ example which reproduces the issue.

Comment: @Spektre the buffers I use to upload the vertex data are both static and final so that pretty much rules out the chance for memory leaks. My renderer uses a deffered pipeline so I'll experiment with different pixel formats for the different buffers when I get home

Comment: @derhass when I enabled the debug log I saw a message stating my vertex format was not 4 byte aligned which could impact preformance. I'll try messing with the vertex pointers to align to 4 bytes per component. This could actually be the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @derhass and @Spektre, the problem was that AMD's windows drivers couldn't properly handle vertex components that weren't aligned on 4-byte boundaries, so using bytes to store normals or rgb colors crashes the driver because the component was only three bytes long. Weird though, how it would work on linux even though it's the same card reading the vertex data.